# Do you know about a good OCMock with GHUnit tutorial in the iPhone / iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ocmock

I'm using GHUnit in my project and i need learn about OCMock for complete my Unit Tests (but i am new to this). I'm working with xcode 3.2.5

somebody knows about a good tutorial on OCMock?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did a quick [google search for "OCMock"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=ocmock) and it found a couple of small tutorials on OCMock. But not in combination with GHUnit. I use this combination and it works very well. OCMock has no problem working within the GHUnit framework. I have both of them in my projects as static frameworks. I'd also suggest have a read through the documentation on the OCMock website. Although I think it's a little light.

Ok, it's not a tutorial but take a look at the sources for [dUsefulStuff](https://github.com/drekka/dUsefulStuff) and [dXml](https://github.com/drekka/dXml). the code is pre me using static frameworks, but it does use both OCMock and GHUnit together. More so in dUsefulStuff which I started after dXml. dXml has around 130 unit tests and dUsefulStuff around 30 or 40 so there should eb enough to give you an idea. I should be updating both of these libaries soon.

Comment: I really should start a blog so I can do tutorials on these things, but I'm really bad at doing diaries :-)